# Fragmentation and ext4

Tags: ext4, sparse-files

Suppose I have a sparse file `F` on a Linux ext4 filesystem, and process `P1` is writing to a disjoint 50% subset of `F` while `P2` writes to the other 50% of `F`.  I would like to minimize fragmentation while the file "grows".  (I put "grows" in quotes because the file is pre-allocated as a sparse file, but as the blocks get written they fill in phantom blocks with actual data.)

I realize since `P1` and `P2` are running in parallel that one may get ahead of the other, but barring this, is it best to have `P1` write blocks 1,3,5,7,... while `P2` writes 2,4,6,...?  Or better to have `P1` write 1,2,3,4,...n/2 and `P2` write n/2+1, ...., n?

Comment: If file fragmentation matters (i.e. it causes performance problems for you), then you should pre-allocate it. Really. Otherwise, it's going to depend on the size of the blocks your application writes compared to the filesystem's block size, and how much free space you have - if low on space/fragmented partition, it won't matter much.

Comment: @Mat I'm worried that `fallocate` (or `posix_fallocate`) will take too long on some OSes, but I'll look into this; cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel caches the writes and lazily flushes them to disk in the background, allocating disk space as it does so in such a way that it minimizes fragmentation.  In other words, you're over thinking things -- don't worry about it.

More specifically when it does to to flush some dirty cache buffers, ext4 goes to allocate enough disk space to hold all of the dirty buffers in the cache, as well as reserving additional space for further growth.

The load you are describing sounds a lot like bit torrent.  I recently downloaded the Ubuntu 11.10 iso via bit torrent and checking it with `filefrag` shows that it is only broken into 3 fragments, which is not bad at all for a 700mb file.